# how to iterate IDataReader or another control

Tags: asp.net, dataset, idatareader

I know I cannot iterate IDataReader to the end and go back to the beginning and iterate it again. So what should I do in order to iterate the data many times?

Comment: Instances of IDataReader are forward-only, read-only, single-shot access to data. You need to use a DataSet filled by a DataAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a number of factors.  You could close and reopen the DataReader, use a dataadapter to read it into a dataset, or create your own collection, read it into that and process off the collection.